# How to convert cell (with different numbers of arrays and empty arrays) to matrix?

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a multidimensional cell that contains empty cells as well as data. I need to convert it to a matrix. But cell2mat(data) does not work since it has cell arrays that contain cell arrays!

```
data =
2x1 cell array
{1x9 cell}
{1x9 cell}
```

I need to get rid of empty cells as well.
Do you have any ideas what I need to change to be able to use cell2mat?

[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve], i.e. write a short piece of code to create a cell array with similar characteristics to your actual array, and show your desired result. By including this in an [edit], we will be better equipped to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have some data:

```
data = { {rand(3,2); []; rand(3,2); rand(3,2)};
         {[]; []; rand(3,2); rand(3,2); []} };
```

You can de-nest this in two stages

1. Stack all elements of the main cell array together

   ```
   data = vertcat( data{:} );
   ```
2. Stack all elements of your new (taller) cell array together, note this discards empties

   ```
   data = vertcat( data{:} );
   ```

Yes, the two steps are the same, just do it twice!

Output for this example is a 15*2 double array (15 rows from 5*3-row random arrays).